# Is there a language/syntax highlighting setting for diff?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to ask a programming question about an internal IDE project file that is changed when files are added and removed from the project ([References to Removed Framework in project.pbxproj File](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40287250/2415822)).  To illustrate this I posted two lines of the git diff to compare the contents of the file from before and after the action.

After posting I realized that I couldn't find a syntax highlight for the output of a diff.  Is diff syntax highlighting available on Stack Overflow or on any other Stack Exchange site?

Comment: Not available according to [this list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/245360) in the FAQ. (Scroll to bottom of the answer)

Comment: You can check the specific [issue](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/480) on the `highlight.js` bug tracker.